# Django model how to add a ManyToManyField on save if condition not reach

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model Article which contain a boolean field.

When I add a new Article, if this bool is True, I want my country (which is a ManyToMayField) to bet set with a specific one.

The bool:

```
global_regions = models.BooleanField('Global', default=True)
```

The ManyTomany:

```
article_country = models.ManyToManyField(Country, verbose_name=_('Country of the article'),
                                 blank=True, null=True,
                                 related_name='country_press_article')
```

I tried to do that :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if (self.article_url[:4] != "http") and (self.article_url[:5] != "https"):
        self.article_url = "https://" + self.article_url
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    if self.global_regions == True: #here is the condition
        self.article_country.add(Country.objects.get(id=257))
    super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But, as I was expecting, it doesn't work.

What should I do if I want it to work ?

Comment: Just an educated guess: when you create a new article, you try to add country before this article is saved to DB (which is done in parent's `.save()`). Try to add country after saving article to DB.

Comment: I totally agree, how would you do it from your model ?

Comment: This is a good candidate for a `m2m_changed` signal.

Comment: I will look for it, thanks !

Comment: Put adding country part after `super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` line (which is responsible for saving article to DB). But you're better of using [`post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save).